# Thunderbolt 3 - calculate bandwith required by monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, bandwidth, displayport, thunderbolt, mst

As described by the [Thunderbolt 3 Technology Brief](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/sites/default/files/Thunderbolt3_TechBrief_FINAL.pdf) DisplayPort signals transmitted over Thunderbolt 3 links have higher priority than PCIe/USB data so in case the total required bandwidth exceeds the maximum bandwidth of 40 Gb/s the PCIe/USB bandwidth will be capped. **I'm trying to understand how much bandwidth will be left for PCIe/USB data on a Thunderbolt 3 connection when daisy chaining multiple monitors**. I'm using the following configuration as an example:

- UHD ("4k" 3840x2160) @ 60 Hz, 30 bit per pixel (an expensive monitor for photo editing)
- UHD ("4k" 3840x2160) @ 60 Hz, 24 bit per pixel (a regular office monitor)

## What I found out so far

- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Thunderbolt_(interface)&oldid=969397748#Thunderbolt_3) Thunderbolt 3 tunnels DisplayPort 1.2, after a [product refresh](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/new-intel%C2%AE-thunderbolt%E2%84%A2-3-controllers-offer-displayport-14-and-basic-peripheral-compatibility-u) DisplayPort 1.4. This is important since DisplayPort 1.4 introduced [Display Stream Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=DisplayPort&oldid=968275706#Display_Stream_Compression). According to the [datasheet of my CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html) it supports only DisplayPort 1.2 (see Table 2-27). For photo editing compression might not be desired anyway.
- According to the [datasheet of my CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html) the bandwidth required by a DisplayPort signal with UHD resolution @ 60 Hz and 24 bit/pixel is 16.00 Gb/s (see Table 2-28). Can someone explain how to calculate this? I tried

  ```
  3840 * 2160 pixels * 24 bit/pixel * 60 Hz * (10/8) = 14.9 Gb/s
  ```

  but although I factored in the [8b/10b encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_interface_bit_rates&oldid=967951309#Digital_video_interconnects) something seems to be missing (some sort of header information?).
- Assuming that the data rate for a 30 bit/pixel signal would be 30/24 times higher and taking into account that Thunderbolt 3 uses 128b/132b encoding, the total bandwidth occupied by DisplayPort data would be 16.5 Gb/s (monitor 1) + 13.2 Gb/s (monitor 2) = 29.7 Gb/s. Assuming that Thunderbolt 3 doesn't add any additional overhead this should leave 10.8 Gb/s for PCIe data transfer (enough for a USB 3.1 link or a 10 GbE adapter). Is this assessment correct?

---

To make the answers to this questions useful for others using different hardware I would appreciate if someone could shine some light on how to calculate the required bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this data rate required calculator:

https://linustechtips.com/topic/729232-guide-to-display-cables-adapters-v2/?section=calc&H=3840&V=2160&F=60&bpc=10&timing=cvtrb&calculations=show&formulas=show

Reproducing the calculations below:

> **Data Rate Required**: 16.00 Gbit/s
>
> Video Format: 3840 × 2160 (16∶9 ratio) at 60 Hz 10 bpc (30 bit/px) RGB
> color Uncompressed CVT-RB timing format
>
> Frame Size: 3,840 × 2,160 = 8,294,400 pixels per frame (8.3 Mpx)
>
> Effective Frame Size with CVT-RB Blanking Intervals: 4,000 × 2,222 =
> 8,888,000 pixels per frame (8.9 Mpx)
>
> Effective Pixel Rate: 8,888,000 px per frame × 60 frames per second =
> 533,280,000 pixels per second
>
> Bit Rate: 533,280,000 px/s × 30 bit/px = **15,998,400,000 bits per second (16.00 Gbit/s)**
>
> **CVT-RB Timing Formula**:
>
> **Constants**:
>
> VMIN = 0.00046 seconds
>
> HBLANK = 160 pixels
>
> **Input Variables**:
>
> H = 3,840 pixels
>
> V = 2,160 pixels
>
> F = 60 Hz
>
> **Formulas**:
>
> VBLANK = (V • VMIN) / (( 1⁄F ) − VMIN)
>
> = (2,160 • 0.00046) / (( 1⁄60 ) − 0.00046)
>
> = ( 61.3 )↑ = 62 pixels
>
> HEFFECTIVE = H + HBLANK = 3,840 + 160 = 4,000 pixels
>
> VEFFECTIVE = V + VBLANK = 2,160 + 62 = 2,222 pixels